# How do I draw a wireframe mesh with hidden lines removed in OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

The cube I want to draw: [image]

The above cube is pretty easy to be created in OpenGL with function `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)`, but it is known that OpenGL ES does not include the function I want to use.
In a word, I don't want to draw cube like this: [image]

I would like to thank the people who could provide any help.

========================least update picture============================

The back edge is a little thinner than front edge. Is there have any solution to solve this problem?

[image]

Current code:

```
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    // Draw edge
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_LINES, lineIndices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, lineIndexBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    GLES20.glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Apply background color and draw faces
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, faceColor, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, triangleIndices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, triangleIndexBuffer);
```

Comment: Why not directly draw the lines? Simply use `GL_LINES` for the primitive type.

Comment: Because I want to draw a 3D model, and the cube will have different angle to see.

Comment: Even if you use GL_LINES you can see it in all the angles, and it is also a 3d model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a standard trick (assumes depth buffer enabled):

1. Draw the mesh edges (lines)
2. Fill the mesh polygons with the background color (to cover up the hidden lines)

Since the mesh edges and the mesh faces will have the same z-values where they meet you need to solve the *z-fighting* problem. The simplest way it use *polygon offset* so that the edges "hover" slightly "above" the polygon faces:

```
gl.disable(gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL)
/* draw polygon edges */
gl.enable(gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
gl.polygonOffset(1.0, 1.0);
/* fill polygons in background color */
```

Here is a wireframe wineglass that illustrates the z-fighting problem:

[image]

Here I solved the z-fighting problem using polygon offset:

[image]

Comment: @BlaiseWang We should change the title to "How do I draw a wireframe mesh with hidden lines removed in OpenGL ES?" And if you like the answer you could upvote it :)

Comment: When I try your solution to the draw cube problem. I found it did work, but you can see the back edges are thinner than front edges in the least picture I posted. Do you have any solution to solve the new problem.

Comment: @BlaiseWang I assume your are using `glLineWidth(w)` with `w  > 1`?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to draw a more complex model to solve it? @wcochran

Comment: @BlaiseWang Are you are also using `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)`? It is possible that the polygon offset needs to be larger (e.g., `gl.polygonOffset(1.0, 2.0)`)  since the filled polygons are covering a portion of the lines.

Comment: No, as far as I know , OpenGL ES 2.0 don't have `GL_LINE_SMOOTH`. My code `glLineWidth(10.0f)`, so I tried many var and I found  `gl.polygonOffset(1.0, 25.0)` is a suitable code. @wcochran

Comment: @BlaiseWang If you have to set the offset that large, you might not have your near and far clipping planes set reasonably for your perspective projection. Try picking values that bracket the nearest and farthest objects as highly as possible.

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand what you're talking about.But if I guess, it might be the `Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);` 's problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79561/discussion-between-wcochran-and-blaise-wang).

Comment: Sorry, I would like to chat with you, but it's 1:30 am here. I have to go to sleep. Any way, I want to thank you again for your help!

Comment: Can you give me further explanation about why I have to set the offset that large ? @wcochran